# Slow App Store Download Times

Tags: app-store, cdn

I'm a developer and I want to speed up the time it takes for a US user to download my app. I'm looking into image compression like ImageOptim and ImageAlpha to reduce the overall file size. But it just seems like App Store downloads are very slow and some users are probably cancelling or forgetting about the download.

This is a long shot but my question is: Is there a way to self-host and use a Content Delivery Network (CDN) to speed up the download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't host your app on a CDN and make it available on the App Store. Just make sure your app binary is as small as possible, on everything else you have basically zero influence.